# How to upload a Video from FileManager to Firebase storage?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a video to firebase storage that is saved in FileManager as a URL looking like this `file:///Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D9BA697D-2ACA-4C4F-BE64-9004016A8500/data/Containers/Data/Application/1133A56A-B92F-4A8A-B9D9-0A8180607B93/Documents/videorecording.mp4`. I tried uploading it like this:

```
private func persistVideoToStorage(id: String, video: URL) {
        let ref = FirebaseManager.shared.storage.reference(withPath: id)
        ref.putData(video, metadata: nil) { metadata, err in
            if let err = err {
                print(err)
                return
            }
            ref.downloadURL { url, err in
                if let err = err {
                        print(err)
                        return
                }
                guard let url = url else { return }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I need to upload the type of Data and cannot convert URL to Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 do {
     let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: video)
     //....
     ref.putData(videoData, metadata: nil)
     //....
 } catch {
     print("-- Error: \(error)")
 }
```